# Obtener valor de celda a la izquierda Excel con VLOOKUP

Tags: excel, vba

Tengo una planilla con varias hojas, donde al escribir un texto en la celda B20 de la hoja 1, en la celda A20 de esa misma hoja me tiene que aparecer el valor 1. Estos textos se deben de escrbir en el rango de celdas desde la B20 hasta la B25 y sus valores (cantidades) en las celdas anteriores.

Por lo tanto en la hoja 2, si escribo un texto en la celda B22 por ejemplo, y ese texto se encuentra en el rango de las celdas B20:B25 de la hoja 1, entonces al valor a su izquierda se le debe sumar 1.

Esto se debe hacer así sucesivamente en todas las hojas y el valor se debe cargar automáticamente.

Adjunto imágenes de ejemplo:

[image: HOJA 1] [image: HOJA 2] [image: HOJA 3]

He intentado con ADDRESS, CELL y MATCH pero no he podido lograr obtener el resultado esperado.

Alguien me puede ayudar?

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bienvenido a SO en español.

No puedes usar VLOOKUP porque esta fórmula solamente devuelve valores que se encuentren a la derecha de la columna de búsqueda. En tus datos, usas la columna de equipos como columna de búsqueda y luego quieres traerte el valor que está a la izquierda, así que no te vale.

Tienes que usar COINCIDIR e ÍNDICE combinadas. Mi fórmula comprueba si el equipo aparece. Si no aparece, devuelve 0. Si aparece, entonces ira el número de la izquierda en la lista, y le suma un 1.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

`=SI(CONTAR.SI($B$20:$B$23;E20)=0;0;1+INDICE($A$20:$B$23;COINCIDIR(E20;$B$20:$B$23;0);1))`

Yo he puesto los datos en la misma hoja, pero la fórmula te sirve igualmente. Solo tienes que actualizar los rangos, que tú los tienes en diferentes hojas. Nada más.

Comment: Muchas gracias @elier-sánchez-e-infantes. Le has salvado la vida a un amigo que se está por recibir de médico y necesita una planilla con algo similar.

Comment: Genial. Si te sirvió la respuesta, por favor, márcala como correcta para que sirva a otros usuarios